# Making a password checker in XML (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

So I'm a beginner in XML/Android and trying to make a password checker in Android Studio. Logically and syntactically, this seems like it should work to me, but it's only calling the first Toast, whether or not I have an upper case in the password.

```java
boolean checkPasswordComplexity(String pw) {
  boolean foundUpperCase, foundLowerCase, foundNumber, foundSpecial;
  foundUpperCase = foundLowerCase = foundNumber = foundSpecial = false;
  char c = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < pw.length(); i++) {
    c = pw.charAt(i);
    if(!Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Missing an upper case letter!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return false;
    } else if (!Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Missing a lower case letter!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return false;
    } else if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Missing a number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return false;
    } else if (!isSpecialCharacter(c)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Missing a special character", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: How is XML involved?

Comment: The more I look at the code the more confused I get. It currently iterates a single time and ignores the "cumulative" flags (`foundXxx`). Did you mean to set the appropriate flag `true` if the char type is found, then at the very end make sure all flags are `true`?

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through a string and on every character you're performing these checks. That means effectively that you will always have at least one error because a single character cannot possibly be upper case, lower case, digit and special.
You're returning from your for loop on the first character. So all your code checks is the first character.

What you need to do is to set your flags inside the loop, and make the evaluation outside of the loop.

With a small refactor on your existing code, this should work.
This will display a single Toast for a single issue.

```java
boolean checkPasswordComplexity(final String pw) {
    boolean foundUpperCase, foundLowerCase, foundNumber, foundSpecial;
    foundUpperCase = foundLowerCase = foundNumber = foundSpecial = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < pw.length(); i++) {
        final char c = pw.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            foundUpperCase = true;
        } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            foundLowerCase = true;
        } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            foundNumber = true;
        } else if (isSpecialCharacter(c)) {
            foundSpecial = true;
        }
    }
    if (!foundUpperCase) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Missing an upper case letter!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (!foundLowerCase) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Missing a lower case letter!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (!foundNumber) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Missing a number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (!foundSpecial) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Missing a special character", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return foundSpecial && foundNumber && foundLowerCase && foundUpperCase;
}
```